# How to get google calendar api freebusy call results localized for "Europe/Warsaw"

Tags: google-api, google-calendar-api

First thing, where I can find list of accepted `timeZone` values?
For simplicity I'm doing this via [google api "try it now" form](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/freebusy/query)
My request:

```
{
   "timeMin":"2014-01-20T13:00:00+01:00",
   "timeMax":"2014-01-20T18:00:00+01:00",
   "items":[
      {
         "id":"XXXXXXX@gmail.com"
      },
      {

      }
   ],
   "timeZone":"Europe/Warsaw"
}
```

returns error:

```
{
   "kind":"calendar#freeBusy",
   "timeMin":"2014-01-20T12:00:00.000Z",
   "timeMax":"2014-01-20T17:00:00.000Z",
   "calendars":{
      "XXXXXXX@gmail.com":{
         "busy":[
            {
               "start":"2014-01-20T15:30:00+01:00",
               "end":"2014-01-20T17:00:00+01:00"
            }
         ]
      },
      "":{
         "errors":[
            {
               "domain":"global",
               "reason":"notFound"
            }
         ],
         "busy":[

         ]
      }
   }
}
```

If i remove `timeZone` property it works but returns UTC times. Do I have a typo in timeZone name? Or it is a google api bug?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To check timezones see this page: [Time Zones by Country](http://www.timezoneconverter.com/cgi-bin/zonehelp.tzc).
It does not look like the error. Your request contains empty object. Try wit this request body:

```
{
  "timeMin": "2014-01-20T13:00:00+01:00",
  "timeMax": "2014-01-20T18:00:00+01:00",
  "timeZone": "Europe/Warsaw",
  "items": 
  [
    {
      "id": "XXXXXXX@gmail.com"
    }
  ]
}
```

Timezone `Europe/Warsaw` is a valid name of the timezone.

Comment: No, order of items doesn’t seem to have any impact

Comment: My example does not contain empty object in `"items"` property.

Comment: Hmm. Strange. It works for me. When I provide timezone, API returns dates in provided timezone.

Comment: Sorry for confusion it works as Michał wrote. I just overworked lately